# Vuetify v-select in Laravel Views

Tags: php, laravel-5, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to use Vuetify in Laravel's Blade Template.
Unfortunately v-select does not seem to return any value.
Maybe you can help me with that.
Everything else works just fine except that.

Laravel Blade:

```
@extends('layouts.vuetify')

@section('content')
    <v-container class="mt-3">
        <h3 class="display-2 mb-3">{{ __('New Company') }}</h3>

        <v-form action="{{ route('company.store') }}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <v-select
                :items="{{ $languages }}"
                :item-text="'name'"
                :item-value="'id'"
                label="Language"
                name="language"
                single-line
                required
            >
            </v-select>
            <v-btn type="submit">{{ __('Save') }}</v-btn>
        </v-form>
    </v-container>
@endsection
```

Passed Items:

```
items: [
    {
        created_at:"2018-10-23 16:24:42",
        id:1,
        name:"English",
        shortcut:"en",
        updated_at:"2018-10-23 16:24:42",
    },
    {
        created_at:"2018-10-23 16:24:42",
        id:2,
        name:"German",
        shortcut:"de",
        updated_at:"2018-10-23 16:24:42",
    }
]
```

Result:

```
+request: ParameterBag {#44 ▼
#parameters: array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "ji0MnnU3U3xW3dmpARbe7fZ8pligEXRAiaCuD0Cc"
  "language" => null
]
```

}

(newbie in stackoverflow)

Comment: Post your code as text

Comment: hopefully it's better now

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Vuetify **in** Laravel before but try removing the inside quotes

`:item-text="'name'"`  --> `:item-text="name"`

`:item-value="'id'"` --> `:item-value="id"`

Take my answer with a pinch of salt.